# anybody knows how to show a complete line in taos shell in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

the query results showed in taos shell are truncated, anybody knows how to disable this truncate? I have tried to use \G, but the output format is different.

```
taos> select * from tb1;
           ts            |     f1      |               f2               |
=========================================================================
 2022-03-31 08:50:44.398 |           1 | Hash Join  (cost=230.47..71... |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.001446s)

taos> select * from tb1\G;
*************************** 1.row ***************************
ts: 2022-03-31 08:50:44.398
f1: 1
f2: Hash Join  (cost=230.47..713.98 rows=101 width=488) (actual time=0.711..7.427 rows=100 loops=1)
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.001340s)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following sql

```
taos> set max_binary_display_width 100;

taos> show stables;
                                                 name                                                 |      created_time       | columns |  tags  |   tables    |
==================================================================================================================================================================
 meters1                                                                                              | 2022-05-26 18:53:58.611 |     121 |      2 |       10000 |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.001390s)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `\G` is OK and there's no difference in your output.

You can also reference to this [FAQ](https://docs.tdengine.com/train-faq/faq/#5-why-are-table-names-not-fully-displayed).